# SIM908 HTTP POST to Google Chrome on android phone

Tags: google-chrome, http, sim900

I would like to create a http server on a SIM900 module. I get the ip address of the sim900 through sms and i open google chrome, insert the ip address in the url.
My sim900 gets the GET request and i made an answer to it like this: (newtork and TCP communication already works)

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://100.96.116.1"
/*this is the current ip address of my phone (got from the GET request) also i tried this without the http tag. I think the problem is here somewhere.*/

OK

AT+HTTPDATA=891,10000 /*i send my data here, there is no problem*/

DOWNLOAD

OK

AT+HTTPACTION=1    /* POST action*/

OK

+HTTPACTION:1,601,0   /* Network error for the POST method */

AT+HTTPTERM    /* terminate http service*/

OK

I'm thinking that there must be some problem with the httppara method and it's ip address, but i'm not sure. Anyone has any idea?

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Sim900 as a server reliably. The reason being that the network operator will quite a few times use natting for cellular network , hence the ip address will not be acessable from another network.

Comment: I am accessing this sim900 server on a mobile gprs network and i can access it in that network from a cell phone and a client server app already works. So i'm looking for the problem.